# Split the word by each character python 3.5

Tags: python, anaconda

> I tried using all the methods suggested by others but its not working.
>   methods like str.split(), lst = list("abcd") but its throwing error saying [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable]
>
> I want to convert string to list for each character in  the word
>   input str=  "abc" should give list = ['a','b','c']

**I want to get the characters of the str in form of list**
    **output - ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] but its giving ['abcdef']**

```
str = "abcdef"
l = str.split()
print l
```

Comment: @MYGz :TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @AbhishekPriyankar Rule1: Don't keep variable names equal to Python keywords. `s1  = "abcdef"; l1=list(s1); print l1`

Comment: Thanks Got it. :)

Comment: @MYGz Technically, `list` isn't a keyword, it's just the name of a built-in type. If you try to assign to a keyword eg, `class`, `for`, `in`, `with`, etc you'll get a syntax error. This question is a great example of   why it's a Bad Idea to use built-in type names as variable names. It _can_ work, but when it doesn't work the error message can be bewildering, especially to newbies who aren't fully conversant with what Python's error messages mean, and only newbies are likely to use built-in type names as variable names.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for dispelling the fallacy my statement was spreading :D

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `list` as a variable name. It will prevent you from doing what you want, because it will shadow the `list` class name.

You can do this by simply constructing a list from the string:

```
l = list('abcedf')
```

sets `l` to the list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f']`

Comment: Well I want lst  = list("abcdef") which throws an error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Just to add, You shouldn't use `str` as variable name either.

Comment: @AbhishekPriyankar remove this line `list = str.split()`.

Comment: Got it ...I was using Ipython shell in Spyder editer . When I ran the code in IDLE , i got the output

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use **list** as name of the variable in your program. It is a defined keyword in python and it is not a good practice.

If you had,

```
str = 'a b c d e f g'
```

then,

```
list = str.split()
print list
>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Since split by default will work on spaces, it Will give what you need.

In your case, you can just use,

```
print list(s)
>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

Q. "I want to convert string to list for each character in the word"

A.  You can use a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Input:

```
new_str = "abcdef"

[character for character in new_str]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop.

input:::

```
str="abc"
li=[]
for i in str:
    li.append(i)
print(li)
#use list function instead of for loop    
print(list(str))
```

output:::

```
["a","b","c"]
["a","b","c"]
```